# Assigning symbolic operators to built-in functions

Tags: symbols, custom-notation

Can I do something like this:

$$\partial_t = D[f, t]$$

i.e. create a symbol instead of a function so that each time I call it, it executes the operation as defined?

Comment: Yes. Look up the `Notations` package in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the notation package something like this is easy. I would never use this by myself, because IMO such *sugar* can easily introduce bugs and undesired behavior if one is not cautious. I will paste a screenshot so that you see how I used the `` Notation` `` package, but first of all you have to load it:

```
<< Notation`
```

then you can use

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Testing it

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

or

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

When I read this question, it seems to be asking for set-delayed. For example, say we want to calculate `D[f[t],t]` over and over but want to give it a name like `q`. Then

```
q := D[f[t], t]
```

does this. If you don't have f defined then

```
q
Derivative[1][f][t]
```

If `f` is defined, say

```
f[t_] := t^2
q
2 t
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually $\partial _t f[t]$ in Mathematica is interpreted as `D[f[t],t]` by default. You don't need to redefine it.

Considering $\partial _t = D[f,t]$ given by the OP is only an example of what the OP wants to do, I regard this question as a way to redefine the basic rules for the input of the expression. You can define the low-level input rules by using `MakeExpression`.

In this case, I try to define $\mathbb{D}_t f[t]$ as `D[f[t],t]` for better understanding.

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\[DoubleStruckCapitalD]", t_], f_}], StandardForm] :=
  MakeExpression[RowBox[{"D", "[", f, ",", t, "]"}], StandardForm]
```

> $\mathbb{D}_t$`f[t]`
>
> `f'[t]`

You can use `FullForm` to check it:

> $\mathbb{D}_t$`f[t]//FullForm`
>
> `Derivative[1][f][t]`

For more details about Low-Level Input and Output Rules, pls read [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LowLevelInputAndOutputRules.html).